# How to include a markdown with in a markdown in angular2-markdown

Tags: angular, npm, markdown

I have a scenario where there is mainmarkdown.md which is the combination of multiple sub markdown like submarkdown1.md,submarkdown2.md, submarkdown3.md (there are separate files which is for a business need)

Right know any changes i make in the content has  to e made in both the places

i.e, if submarkdown2.md changes i have to change submarkdown2.md and mainmarkdown.md which is a problem

is there a way to include submarkdown2.md in mainmarkdown.md

where i tried from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-markdown

to implement some thing like below which is not working

```
<div Markdown path="/path/to/readme.md"></div>
```

Please suggest any other npm module or with the same module how to achieve it